# Comments for documentation PHP post data and returning JSON

Tags: php, documentation, comments, psr-4, zf3

I have two questions actually:

1. For some functions I am posting forms to them, can I mention them as `@params` in comments or what:

   ```
   /* some descriptions 
    *
    * @param string userName
    */



   public function add(){ 
              $userName = $_POST['user']
           ......
   }
   ```
2. From some function I am returning data as JSON, how to mention JSON as return type and format:

   ```
    /* some descriptions 
     *
     * @return JSON [{id, name,...}]
     */
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write anything you like in comments. That said, it's not a conventional use - `@param` and `@return` should describe the actual parameters and return values of the function in question. See e.g. the [draft PHP-FIG recommendation](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) for what's (mostly) conventional.

If you're returning a JSON string it would be better to document it as

`@return string Text here describing what is being returned`

since as far as PHP is concerned it's just another string.